Exporting fbx file with textures models ara black or transparent
I have huge problem with my fbx file. The models are just black or transparent. I feel like I have tried everything.
Maybe you will be able to find a problem.


https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos I baked these textures and also tried to use other ways to make it right :( thats why i decided to ask this question here

Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

I would guess try removing the Alpha input. If you aren't masking anything that might cause an issue like this. But we can't be sure until we actually see the blendfile

I had that problem at one point. It could be that your meshes have multiple UV maps, and Blender is choosing the first one by default. You should remove the ones that are not needed. You can do this in the Properties panel, under the Data tab, where you'll find a dropdown menu to manage UV maps.


Ooo! Thank u so much! I would never think that it could be that type of reason :D
